# How can I use the CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE option with pycurl and Python?

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm trying to use [CURL's CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE option](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTMAXRECVSPEEDLARGE) with the pycurl library. Here is my test code:

```python
import sys
import pycurl


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = ''

    def body_callback(self, buf):
        self.contents = self.contents + buf

print >>sys.stderr, 'Testing', pycurl.version

t = Test()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://curl.haxx.se/dev/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, t.body_callback)
c.setopt(c.CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 1024)
c.perform()
c.close()

print t.contents
```

It produces an error; there does not seem to be a library constant defined for this option.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nilayanand/Documents/workspace/photofeed/photofeed-desktop/test/curl.py", line 18, in <module>
    c.setopt(c.CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 1024)
AttributeError: CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE
```

How can I use the CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE option with pycurl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute for the `CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE` option doesn't include the `CURLOPT_` prefix, it is just named `MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE`. Your code works if you correct the line that uses it to be:

```
c.setopt(c.MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 1024)
```

Comment: Great! I'd you'd like you can mark this as the solution for future viewers by pressing the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will work, but you can try to change this line

```
c.setopt(c.CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 1024)
```

with this line

```
c.setopt(CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 1024)
```

Comment: He didn't `import * from pycurl` or anything, so there's no way for `CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE` will be defined. This must cause an error.

Comment: No luck with either importing * or directly using CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE.

Comment: Here is what their manual says:

Pass a curl_off_t as parameter. If a download exceeds this speed (counted in bytes per second) on cumulative average during the transfer, the transfer will pause to keep the average rate less than or equal to the parameter value. Defaults to unlimited speed. (Added in 7.15.5)
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTMAXRECVSPEEDLARGE